# ¿El reset solo funciona en la primera fila?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdo

#El reset solo funciona en la primera fila. Al agrega una segunda fila el reset me borrar la primera fila al cumplirse la condición.

con este codigo

`document.getElementsByClassName("kmactual")[0].value = "";` me hace el reset.

Que esta en esta condición

```
MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MAYOR QUE EL KILOMETRAJE ANTERIOR ..!!";
$("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE); 
$("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
document.getElementsByClassName("kmactual")[0].value = "";
```

Este código borrar el dato de un input al no cumplirse. Como les escribi mas arriba al ingresar en la primera fila un valor menor aparece el mensaje y se borra el dato ingresado. Al agregar otra fila e ingrasar el dato que no cumpla me borra el de la primera fila

```
<script>

  $("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'input.kmactual', function() {
  var contenido = document.getElementsByClassName("kilometraje_actual")[0].value; 
  var contenido_km_motor = document.getElementsByClassName("km_motor")[0].value;
  var contenido_km_caja = document.getElementsByClassName("km_caja")[0].value;
  var contenido_km_diferencial = document.getElementsByClassName("km_diferencial")[0].value;
  var contenido_km_adblue = document.getElementsByClassName("km_adblue")[0].value;
  

    var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
    $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
    valor = $select.val();

    var calculo_km_motor=parseInt(contenido_km_motor) + parseInt(5000);
    var calculo_km_caja=parseInt(contenido_km_caja) + parseInt(5000);
    var calculo_km_diferencial=parseInt(contenido_km_diferencial) + parseInt(5000);
    var calculo_km_adblue=parseInt(contenido_km_adblue);

  if (parseInt(valor) > parseInt(contenido)) {
   
    if (parseInt(valor) < parseInt(calculo_km_motor)) {
         
         if (parseInt(valor) < parseInt(calculo_km_caja)) {

            if (parseInt(valor) < parseInt(calculo_km_diferencial)) {

                if (parseInt(valor) < parseInt(calculo_km_adblue) || parseInt(calculo_km_adblue) >= 0) {
  

                      var total = valor - contenido;
                      $tr.find("input.diferencia_km").val(total);
             }else{ 

        MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MENOR QUE EL KILOMENTRAJE DE LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE FILTRO DE ADBLUE. SI YA REALIZO LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE FILTRO DE ADBLUE. VERIFICAR SI INGRESO LA MANTENCION EN EL REGISTRO DE MANTENCIONES";
                 $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
                 $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');}
   
       }else{ 

        MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MENOR QUE EL KILOMENTRAJE DE LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DEL DIFERENCIAL. SI YA REALIZO LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DEL DIFERENCIAL. VERIFICAR SI INGRESO LA MANTENCION EN EL REGISTRO DE MANTENCIONES";
                 $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
                 $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
    }

           }else{ 

 MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MENOR QUE EL KILOMENTRAJE DE LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DE LA CAJA. SI YA REALIZO LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DE LA CAJA. VERIFICAR SI INGRESO LA MANTENCION EN EL REGISTRO DE MANTENCIONES";
                 $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
                 $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');

    }
           }else{ 
   MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MENOR QUE EL KILOMENTRAJE DE LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DEL MOTOR. SI YA REALIZO LA MANTENCION DEL CAMBIO DE ACEITE DEL MOTOR. VERIFICAR SI INGRESO LA MANTENCION EN EL REGISTRO DE MANTENCIONES";
                 $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
                 $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');

 }
}else{
   
   
   MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MAYOR QUE EL KILOMETRAJE ANTERIOR ..!!";
    $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
    $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');  

    document.getElementsByClassName("kmactual")[0].value = "";
    
}




    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diria que en lugar de esto:

```javascript
document.getElementsByClassName("kmactual")[0].value = "";
```

necesitas hacer esto:

```javascript
$(this).val("")
```

porque si te fijas en el inicio de toda la función:

```
$("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'input.kmactual', function() {
```

el `$(this)` de esa función ya está representando el `input.kmactual` que está recibiendo ese evento `change`, por lo tanto ya puedes usarlo directamente en lugar de intentar usar la función *getElementsByClassName*.

La función [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) de jquery es similar a la propiedad value de javascript.

Dicha función *getElementsByClassName* contiene todos los elementos de esa clase que le pasas como parámetro (**kmactual**), y no va a saber decirte donde estás si tu no se lo dices, y en tu caso el error es que le dices que es el primer elemento con la clase `kmactual` al agregarle el número de indice con esta sintaxis `[0]`, y por eso te cambia el primero solo.

Comment: aveces me quedo bloqueado por cosas tan simples :(. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Es normal, vamos, es lo habitual... muchas veces tienes toda la lógica bien pero después pequeños fallos de sintaxis o de funciones te hacen dudar de todo, je :-)